# Parsing the required field from an URL in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a requirement which is to parse the required field from an URL. For this purpose I need to traverse that URL letter by letter since  there is no space separation between any words . But I am not able to get that . I have tried the below

```
awk '{FS = "";for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {print $i}}'  file
```

The file contains this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit?s=sddasdsadSOMEFIELD=8171**WANTEDFIELD=121212**SOMEFIELD=1201212...

So my idea is to traverse this URL letter by letter and then reach the required field .. But I am not able to do that. Any suggestions please

Comment: You need to define how to recognise "WANTEDFIELD". Is it always the second thing of the form "ALPHAS=NUMS", or is it always between two literal "SOMEFIELD"? The answer is probably regular expressions, but you need to provide more detail.

Comment: is your wanted field consistent? If yes what it is?

Comment: I am sorry for this guys .. The WANTEDFIELD is undefined .. The position of the same is not known ...

Comment: Do u guys need some more details ?

Comment: Yes, we do. How do you know when you've found it?

Answer (score 1):

This could work, but is assuming the pattern with = and *.

```
echo "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit?s=sddasdsadSOMEFIELD=8171*WANTEDFIELD=121212*SOMEFIELD=1201212..." |awk -F "[*=]" -vFIELDNAME="WANTEDFIELD"  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(match($i,FIELDNAME)){printf "%s\t", $(i+1)}};printf "\n"}'
```

output:

```
121212
```

changing to SOMEFIELD as target field:

```
echo "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit?s=sddasdsadSOMEFIELD=8171*WANTEDFIELD=121212*SOMEFIELD=1201212..." | awk -F "[*=]" -vFIELDNAME="SOMEFIELD"  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(match($i,FIELDNAME)){printf "%s\t", $(i+1)}};printf "\n"}'
```

results in:

```
8171    1201212...
```